# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input false error

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just The last "}" shows a error for no reason.
A "}" is a death?
VIIIth attempt.
A coding job makes my brain kinda melt.
Send help! I am freaking out!
Can't fix this.
Return 1;
I am almost losing my mind.
Pot of 1 and 0s'.
Thanks if you read this btw just read the first letter on the first words on start of the sentences.

```js
console.error("1010101 011110 1010101010 1001 0101010100 1001 010001001");
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';   
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
     result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
  return result;
  console.log(makeid(29));
}

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
 console.log("Submitted prize. Prize ID:");
  function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
   console.log(makeid(27));
}
  
document.getElementById("acceptpol").onclick = function() {
  console.log("Accepted promise. Promise ID:");
  function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
   console.log(makeid(29));
}
function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
   return result;
   console.log(makeid(11));
}
```

```css
h1{
 color: green;
}
label{
 color: green;
}
input{
 color: green;
}
body,html{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url('smile.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <h1> Press F12 in your keyboard to see your promise, submit and your contact ID </h1>
  <h1> ENTER YOUR INFORMATION TO CLAIM YOUR PRIZE! </h1>
   <label for="fname">First name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
   <label for="lname" id="lname">Last name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
   <label for="emailadd">E-Mail Address (So we can contact to you):</label>
   <input type="text" id="emailadd" name="emailadd"><br><br>
   <label for="address">Your Home Address</label>
   <input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br><br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="acceptpol">accept to contact to us when your prize when it's not in your address</input> 
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
 </body>
 <head>
  <title> TriviaAwards.com </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: why so many `makeid`'s?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing 2 closing brackets in your javascript you don't close the document.getElementById functions:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
 console.log("Submitted prize. Prize ID:");
  function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
    console.log(makeid(27));
  }
} // add this
```

Same for the other getElementById function.
If you keep your indentation the same you can prevent these errors.